# How do I describe the method header for a large number of input parameters which are the elements of array?

Tags: java

```
final JTextField tf[] = null;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        tf[i] = new JTextField("");
```

How to transfer these parameters to describing method?

If I wouldn't use the array, the method header looked like

```
public void input (JTextField tf1,JTextField tf2,JTextField tf3, JTextField tf4, JTextField tf5){...}
```

I have to optimize the code in order to avoid unnecessary actions.

Comment: Please explain your question better, it makes no sense

Comment: Based on your title you could be looking for varargs but that is just a guess. You need to [[edit]] your question and add more info of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Much better, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void input (JTextField... tf)
{

    final JTextField tf[] = null;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {

        tf[i] = new JTextField("");
    }   

}
```

Using ... sets up an unspecified number of JTextFields. This allows you to have as many as you want in a parameter

Comment: What is the purpose of `final JTextField tf[] = null;`?

Comment: @Pshemo Loooool, I don't have a clue, that was what the OP put in, I just worked around it.

Comment: @Pshemo The loop doesn't work without initializing the array.

Comment: @user3484031 `tf[] = null` will not initialize array, but will set `tf` reference to `null`. Anyway I still don't see what problem you are trying to solve so I am not sure if this answer is what you are looking for. Your question looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Pshemo I need to place text fields on a frame one above the other, but I want to get this automated using loops including creating and passing these tf[] elements to method of another class.

Comment: @user3484031 Varargs `JTextField... tf` is in fact array which will let you accept its elements like you described in your question (like `input(new JTextField("foo"), new JTextField("bar"))`). But since `tf` already represents array with elements passed to method you shouldn't (and can't) redeclare it inside method like this answer does (that is why I asked about it in my first comment under this answer).

Comment: @Pshemo I don't use this code in my program. Now I have another problem. How to describe and initialize properly the initial array of objects of JTextField class without using null?

Comment: @user3484031 Please put that into another question and link it here

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328751/how-to-automate-properly-describing-and-initializing-jtextfield-class-objects-in)